# Facebook: "URL could not be liked because it has been blocked" error in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm working on an iOS app that allows the user to like a Facebook page within the app. I've implemented this using [FacebookLikeView](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView). During the course of testing this functionality, I've liked and unliked the same page multiple times. Unfortunately, this seems to have triggered Facebook's spam detection. Now, when trying to like a page using the like button displayed by FacebookLikeView, the following error is presented: "URL could not be liked because it has been blocked".

Based on reports of the same problem found by searching the web, I've filled out [this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=244560538958131) to request that Facebook remove the block. However, I've received no response from them. I'm not sure how to proceed. Has anyone else run into this issue and successfully solved it?

Comment: In most cases, days elapsed without "suspicious" activity will auto-unblock the app.  Number of days probably varies / different for each case.

Comment: Thanks Donn, I'll wait a few days and try again.

Comment: Regarding the downvote and close vote, I understand that this question isn't about a specific algorithm and doesn't include source code. However, it is a "practical, answerable question based on [an] actual problem that [I] face". It's something that I know other programmers have faced and will face in working on implementing a specific functionality. Also, Facebook holds facebook.stackoverflow.com up as one of the official channels for developer support. If I can't ask this question here, where can I ask it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*With billions of pieces of content being shared on Facebook every month and bad actors constantly targeting the people who use Facebook, preventing spam isn't easy. Just as a community relies on its citizens to report crime, we rely on you to let us know when you encounter spam, which can be anything from a friend request sent by someone you don't know to a message that includes a link to a malicious website.*

From : [Explaining Facebook Spam Detection](https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=403200567130)

This is no answer and what Donn Lee said is maybe the best answer.

My best guess at this is to send them lot information regarding you testing the app rather than abusing the system. You could try screenshots, contact info and explain what you are testing it for.

Try : [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/)

Developer Help : [Rate Limits, Restrictions and Disables](https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=100502990045478)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and have accepted. So that others finding this question in the future know, I wanted to mention that this has not actually led to a resolution. I've filled out the block removal request form including very thorough explanations of our app and the problem, with no response from Facebook whatsoever. It seems we're just stuck...

Comment: Sorry to hear that - but yeah, you are right. Facebook is a large company and as friendly as they can be, they can't post to everything sent to them. You might get an answer or you might not. Best thing you can do (from personal experience) is to remind them every now and then, possibly each week - two weeks with a reminder that you are still here and still want to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try filing a bug on the [Facebook Developers Bugreporter](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).

If it's been a week and the site is still blocked, submit your site on [this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=244560538958131).

if it comes down to no other option, there is also unrelated contact info on [Facebook Newsroom](http://newsroom.fb.com), including the e-mail address [press@fb.com](http://mailto%3apress@fb.com).