# Implement a 'Like our Facebook page' button on IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

After looking through several related topics and web articles it seems many of them was written before IOS6 and the integration to Facebook.

What I'm looking to do it add a LIKE button within my application that the user can press which will then like our facebook page.

What is the best way to do this?

Facebook IOS SDK?

Facebook OpenGraph?

Is there any good up-to-date tutorials out there?

Comment: I'd start with the [iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/ios). This will have the most up-to-date information from Facebook about developing on iOS.

Comment: +1 For interest in answer

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Like' a page using Facebook API or just access\_token](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12551960/like-a-page-using-facebook-api-or-just-access-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think the Facebook SDK would be the best place to start. iOS6 implements a lot of functionality with Facebook, and frankly, after I was done reading through some of it, it did a lot that I had no idea it even could.

This tutorial helped a lot:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

But, perhaps this is more what you are looking for (?):
http://angelolloqui.com/blog/10-Facebook-Like-Button-on-iOS

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [FacebookLikeView](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView) project with (initial) success. Unfortunately, my app was [blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182286/facebook-url-could-not-be-liked-because-it-has-been-blocked-error-in-ios-app), apparently due to triggering Facebook's spam detection during development and testing of the app (liking/unliking my own page a number of times). I haven't found a way around that problem, and it is something that others have seen too.